# using subset with a string in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame in R (made up stuff to learn the program):

```
country population civilised
```

1      Town         13         5
2      city         69         9
3      Home         24         2
4     Stuff         99         9

and I am trying to access specific rows with the subset function, like
test <- subset(t, country==Town. But all ever get is object not found.

Answer (score 0):

We need to quote the string.

```
 test <- subset(t, country=='Town')
 test
 #  country population civilised
 #1    Town         13         5
```

NOTE; `t` is a function name (Check `?t`).  It is better to name objects that are not function names.